# altering values for List (text) error: Allowed values list: some values are being removed while currently in use

Tags: drupal-7, content-type

I have a drupal 7 site with content type that has a field of type List (text)   and widget is Select list, I wanted to alter the allowed values but unable to because I keep getting an error:
Allowed values list: some values are being removed while currently in use.

What do you suggest? maybe change it through PHPmyadmin for existing nodes?

Comment: Duplicate of: [How can I remove items from the allowed values list of a select field that has data for the values?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112315/how-can-i-remove-items-from-the-allowed-values-list-of-a-select-field-that-has-d)

Comment: sure, except I asked this 4 months ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is not much delete the field values entered earlier and 
then alter the allowed values.
After that you can reenter the the field values added.